# updating date delete the row in sqlite android

Tags: android-sqlite

I have a problem when i try to update a field that contains date (as text) the sqlexecsql(sql) or rawquery(sql) delete the row. 
I don't know why delete the row. If someone can help me, I'll be grateful

```
CREATE TABLE [Study](
  [IdMedicalStudy] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  [Fecha] TEXT, 
  [IdDoctor] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [Doctors]([IdDoctor]) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  [IdTypeOfMedicalStudy] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [TypeOfMedicalStudy]([IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy]) ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  [IdMedicalStudyPlace] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [MedicalStudyPlace]([IdMedicalStudyPlace]) ON UPDATE CASCADE);

public void updateRow (ContentValues contentValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "UPDATE " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY + " SET "
                + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE + " = '"
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE).toString().trim()
                + "', " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY _PLACE + " = "
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY _PLACE)
                + ", " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR + " = "
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR)
                + ", " + ConstDB.TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE OF MEDICAL STUDY + " = "
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_ID_TYPE OF MEDICAL STUDY)
                + " WHERE " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY + " = "
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY);
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Row updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think that it has deleted a row? You should edit your question to include what the data looks like before the update and after the update highlighting row() that have apparently been deleted. Odds on a row hasn't been deleted, rather than it's been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in the above code, such as spaces where spaces are not allowed, but after

- recreating the code with errors removed
- creating some underlying code to create all the required tables
- adding some methods to add data to the referenced tables and of course the **Study** table
- adding some methods to dump the data in the tables

  - logAll (sequentially retrieves all rows from each tables into a cursor and dumps the cursor)
  - logStudy (specific for the Study table, used by logAll)
- changing to use the **update** convenience method rather than using the **execSQL** method.
- removing the all too confusing try/catch clause

**Testing shows that the code in-principle (with the above changes/corrections) works and doesn't lose data.**

### Working Example Code

### ConstDB.java

This was constructed based upon your code but may well differ :-

```
public class ConstDB {

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE = "[TypeOfMedicalStudy]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE_ID = "[IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STYUDY_TYPE_NAME = "[TypeName]";

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR = "[Doctors]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_ID = "[IdDoctor]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_NAME = "[DoctorName]";

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE = "[MedicalStudyPlace]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_ID = "[IdMedicalStudyPlace]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_NAME = "[PlaceName]";



    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY = "[Study]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE = "[fecha]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR = "[IdDoctor]";
    public static final String TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY = "[IdTypeOfMedicalStudy]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY = "[IdMedicalStudy]";
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE = "[IdMedicalStudyPlace]";

    //TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE

    /*
    CREATE TABLE [Study](
  [IdMedicalStudy] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  [Fecha] TEXT,
  [IdDoctor] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [Doctors]([IdDoctor]) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  [IdTypeOfMedicalStudy] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [TypeOfMedicalStudy]([IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy]) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  [IdMedicalStudyPlace] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES [MedicalStudyPlace]([IdMedicalStudyPlace]) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
     */

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_CREATESQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY +
            "(" +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE," +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE + " TEXT," +

            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR + " INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES " +TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR +
            "(" + TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_ID + ") ON UPDATE CASCADE," +

            TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY + " INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES " + TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE +
            "(" + TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE_ID + ") ON UPDATE CASCADE," +

            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE + "INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES " + TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE +
            "(" + TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_ID + ") ON UPDATE CASCADE" +
            ")";

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE_CREATESQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE +
            "(" +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STYUDY_TYPE_NAME + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_CREATESQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR +
            "(" +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_NAME + " TEXT" +
            ")";

    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_CREATESQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE + "(" +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_NAME + " TEXT" +
            ")";

}
```

- Note I found the naming conventions very confusing.

### DBHelper.java

I didn't see any reference to the class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper (typically referred to as the Database Helper), so this is an equivalent to what you have.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    Context mContext;

    public static final String DBNAME = "ms";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_CREATESQL);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE_CREATESQL);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_CREATESQL);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_CREATESQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addStudyType(String studyTypeName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TABLE_MEDICAL_STYUDY_TYPE_NAME,studyTypeName);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE,null,cv);
    }

    public long addDoctor(String doctorName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR_NAME,doctorName);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR,null,cv);
    }

    public long addPlace(String placeName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE_NAME,placeName);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE,null,cv);
    }

    public long addStudy(String date, long doctor, long type, long place) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE,date);
        cv.put(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR,doctor);
        cv.put(TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY,type);
        cv.put(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE,place);
        return mDB.insert(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY,null,cv);
    }


    public void updateRow (ContentValues contentValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "UPDATE " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY + " SET "
                + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE + " = '"
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE).toString().trim()
                //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT + "', " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY _PLACE + " = " //<<<<<<<<<< extra space
                + "', " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE + " = "
                //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT+ contentValues.get(ConstDB.ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY _PLACE) //<<<<<<<<<< extra space
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE)
                + ", " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR + " = "
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR)
                //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT + ", " + ConstDB.TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE OF MEDICAL STUDY + " = "
                + ", " + ConstDB.TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY + " = "
                //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT+ contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_ID_TYPE OF MEDICAL STUDY)
                + contentValues.get((ConstDB.TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY))
                + " WHERE " + ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY + " = "
                + contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY);

        //<<<<<<<<<< try/catch block will not necessarily indicate row not update
        //<<<<<<<<<< Betwer way is to use the update convenience methdo which returns the number of rows updated
        /*
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Row updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close();
        }
        */

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE, contentValues.get(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE).toString().trim());
        cv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE, contentValues.getAsLong(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE));
        cv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR, contentValues.getAsLong(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR));
        cv.put(TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY, contentValues.getAsLong(ConstDB.TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY));
        String whereclause = ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(contentValues.getAsLong(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY))};
        int rv = mDB.update(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY, cv, whereclause, whereargs);
        if (rv < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Row not updated.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Updated " + String.valueOf(rv) + " rows",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

    public void logAll() {
        Cursor c;
        c = mDB.query(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_TYPE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
        c = mDB.query(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DOCTOR,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
        c= mDB.query(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_STUDY_PLACE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
        logStudy();
    }

    public void logStudy() {
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mDB.query(TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY,null,null,null,null,null,null));
    }

    public ContentValues preapreCVForUpdate(long studyId, String studyDate, long doctorId, long type, long place) {
        ContentValues rv = new ContentValues();
        rv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY,studyId);
        rv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_DATE,studyDate);
        rv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_DOCTOR,doctorId);
        rv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_TABLE_ID_TYPE_OF_MEDICAL_STUDY,type);
        rv.put(ConstDB.TABLE_MEDICAL_STUDY_ID_MEDICAL_STUDY_PLACE,place);
        return rv;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

This is a simple Activity that was used to test creating the tables, populating them with some testing data and finally updating the data with the modified/corrected **updateRow** method :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        mDBHlpr.addDoctor("Mary");
        mDBHlpr.addDoctor("Sue");
        mDBHlpr.addDoctor("Fred");
        mDBHlpr.addDoctor("Tom");

        mDBHlpr.addStudyType("Skeletal");
        mDBHlpr.addStudyType("Cardial");
        mDBHlpr.addStudyType("Cranial");
        mDBHlpr.addStudyType("Abdominal");

        mDBHlpr.addPlace("Home");
        mDBHlpr.addPlace("St. Barts");
        mDBHlpr.addPlace("Paddington");
        mDBHlpr.addPlace("London School of Medicine");

        mDBHlpr.addStudy("2019-01-01 10:30",2,3,3);
        mDBHlpr.addStudy("2019-01-02 12:45",1,1,1);
        mDBHlpr.addStudy("2019-01-03 15:25",3,2,4);

        mDBHlpr.logAll();

        mDBHlpr.updateRow(mDBHlpr.preapreCVForUpdate(2,"2019-01-02 16:45",4,4,2));

        mDBHlpr.logStudy();
    }
}
```

### Results

With regard to the update the row with the id of 2 is added as :-

```
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-02 12:45
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=1
```

After the Update is becomes :-

```
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-02 16:45
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=2
```

Which tallies with

```
mDBHlpr.updateRow(mDBHlpr.preapreCVForUpdate(2,"2019-01-02 16:45",4,4,2));
```

Saying update the Study row that has an ID of 2 to 
- have a date of 2019-01-01
- reference the row from the Doctors table that has an ID of 4 (Tom)
- reference the row from the Type tables that has an ID of 4 (Abdominal)
- reference the row from the Place that has and ID of 2 (St. Barts)

Which as can be seen has done.

The log in full was :-

```
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@fe54ec2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    TypeName=Skeletal
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    TypeName=Cardial
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.201 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    TypeName=Cranial
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 3 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTTypeOfMedicalStudy=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    TypeName=Abdominal
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@eadd4d3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    DoctorName=Mary
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.202 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    DoctorName=Sue
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    DoctorName=Fred
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 3 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    DoctorName=Tom
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-01-17 14:34:23.203 4595-4595/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@50e1810
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    PlaceName=Home
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    PlaceName=St. Barts
2019-01-17 14:34:23.204 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    PlaceName=Paddington
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 3 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    PlaceName=London School of Medicine
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@eb54f09
2019-01-17 14:34:23.205 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-01 10:30
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-02 12:45
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.206 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.207 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-03 15:25
2019-01-17 14:34:23.207 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.207 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.207 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.207 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.207 4595-4595/? I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@adad2c5
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=1
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-01 10:30
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-02 16:45
2019-01-17 14:34:23.211 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudy=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    fecha=2019-01-03 15:25
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdDoctor=3
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdTypeOfMedicalStudy=2
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out:    IdMedicalStudyPlace=4
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out: }
2019-01-17 14:34:23.212 4595-4595/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```